# Cognos Hyperion Essbase connection

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

We have cognos analytics which we want to connect to Hyperion cube but domain network in which they both are present are different because Hyperion is an application which over parent company owns and Cognos is owned by the my company which is a sister company to corporate.

Is their any other way we can access the Hyperion cube directly in cognos.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Oracle Essbase data source available within the IBM Cognos Administration\Configuration.

If you are using the compatible query mode(CQM) you'll need to install the Essbase client, set the environment variables and possibly adjust the cqe_config.xml depending on your version.

If you are using the dynamic query mode(DQM) you'll need to copy the Jar files into the drivers folder within the Report Server install.

All the above is covered in more detail via the following link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.dyn_query.10.2.2.doc/t_dqm_olap_install_drivers.html

Comment: We were trying to access the data using WebAPI because we cannot directly connect to the Essbase database.We were using XMLA connection and connection got successful in IBM Cognos Configuration but when we open the Framework Manager to create a package we are getting error saying a XML file is expected.

Comment: The only XMLA connection I can see is for SSAS, how did you define your connection?

Comment: WE used the SSAS XMLA connection and provide the URL which directly access the Hyperion Cube Webservice and it is a SOAP web service,

Comment: I am not sure you are going to be able to create the required Essbase stub file by attempting to trick the connection.  This is most likely what is causing the error.  Even if you were to get this going, given you've switched the provider you'll most likely run into performance and or function issues.